# When is a NoSuchElementException thrown for a call to flow.single()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Say I have an API like so:

```
interface Foo {
   val barFlow: Flow<Bar>
}
```

And I consume it like so:

```
class FooConsumer(private val foo: Foo) {
   init {
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
           val bar = foo.barFlow.single()
           println("Collected bar: $bar)
       }
   }
}
```

According to the docs for `single` a `NoSuchElementException` can be thrown if the flow is empty. However, this confuses me quite a lot, as a terminal operation on a flow will "await" elements of the flow to be emitted. So how will the call to `single` know that there were no elements in the flow? Maybe an element just hasn't been emitted yet?

I mean under the hood, the call to `single` is collecting the source flow before it does the check. Therefore at least 1 item must have been emitted before the check for null is carried out, so that null check should never succeed and a `NoSuchElementException` should never be thrown (for the case where the flow is of a non nullable type).

So will `NoSuchElementException` only be a possibility for flows of nullable types?

Here is the source code for `single`:

```
/**
 * The terminal operator, that awaits for one and only one value to be published.
 * Throws [NoSuchElementException] for empty flow and [IllegalStateException] for flow
 * that contains more than one element.
 */
public suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.single(): T {
    var result: Any? = NULL
    collect { value ->
        if (result !== NULL) error("Expected only one element")
        result = value
    }

    if (result === NULL) throw NoSuchElementException("Expected at least one element")
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return result as T
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`NoSuchElementException` is thrown when the Flow finishes its emission without emitting a single element. One case I can think of right now is when you need to turn a collection into a Flow source. If that collection is empty and you call `single` on that Flow you will get a `NoSuchElementException`.

This example may seem absurd but you get the point:

```
val emptyListFlow = emptyList<Int>().asFlow()

launch {
    val data = emptyListFlow.single()
}
```

Comment: So a flow has an end then? I thought it was something like an infinite stream.

Comment: @ThomasCook Sure, it might end. Once it finishes the coroutine that called the terminal operator continues its execution in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made a list.first(), where the list was empty